# How do I serve static files from a different URL with Dart?

Tags: dart

With Dart, I've got `awesome.html`, but I'd like it to be `/awesome`.  Is this purely an `.htaccess` (I'm using Apache) thing, or is there a way to go about this the Dart or "modern web development" way?

This `.htaccess` bit directs `/awesome` to `/awesome.html`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1.html [L]
```

But then all my relative URL references (to css/js/images) break, and if I rewrite them from "assets/whatever" to "/assets/whatever" it'll break when working in the Dart Editor since it uses URLs like:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3030/Users/dave/Sites/my-dart-app/web/awesome.html
```

Ideas?  Best practices?  Thank you!

Comment: I believe a framework would help here a lot. As it stands now, there is no simple way to do this, so, a routing system is needed. I'm actually working on one, but it's not ready yet.

Comment: I assume you're talking about a Dart server-side application?

Comment: @SethLadd, it's just a set of simple client-side pages right now, though I understand that I'll need a server-side app going to get funky w/ how I serve pages, as in your answer below.

Answer (score 5):

thanks for the question!

The answer depends on if you have a proxy or web server in front of your Dart server VM. If you have a proxy in front, then the proxy can do the URL rewriting before the request hits your Dart VM. This is a nice scenario anyway, because a proxy can do caching, SSL, load balancing, and more. The Dart VM is then just an "app server" in this scenario. I would recommend placing an industrial strength web server or proxy in front just as a best practice.

However, if you want to do URL masking and rewriting purely in Dart, here is some code. As Kai says in the comments above, this is generally a framework's job. But I'll include some code here anyway for fun. :)

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:json';

class StaticFileHandler {
  final String basePath;

  StaticFileHandler(this.basePath);

  _send404(HttpResponse response) {
    response.statusCode = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
    response.outputStream.close();
  }

  String rewritePath(String path) {
    String newPath = path;

    if (path == '/' || path.endsWith('/')) {
      newPath = '${path}index.html'; 
    } else if (!path.endsWith('.html')) {
      newPath = "${path}.html";
    }

    return newPath;
  }

  // TODO: etags, last-modified-since support
  onRequest(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) {
    String path = rewritePath(request.path);

    final File file = new File('${basePath}${path}');
    file.exists().then((found) {
      if (found) {
        file.fullPath().then((String fullPath) {
          if (!fullPath.startsWith(basePath)) {
            _send404(response);
          } else {
            file.openInputStream().pipe(response.outputStream);
          }
        });
      } else {
        _send404(response);
      }
    });
  }

}

runServer(String basePath, int port) {
  HttpServer server = new HttpServer();

  server.defaultRequestHandler = new StaticFileHandler(basePath).onRequest;
  server.onError = (error) => print(error);
  server.listen('127.0.0.1', 1337);
  print('listening for connections on $port');
}

main() {
  var script = new File(new Options().script);
  var directory = script.directorySync();
  runServer("${directory.path}", 1337);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Seth! I recognize that code from the chat app.  Yes, I imagine I want to go with "an industrial strength web server or proxy in front" as you say.  Can you help me understand the difference between a proxy and a web server?  Which proxy or web servers would you recommend?  Been a long-time LAMP person, so Apache is what I'm used to, but are there recommendations for the server-side stack w/ Dart?

Comment: I'd say "go with what you know", and Apache can act as a proxy. It's possible that Apache or nginx are more performant serving raw static files, but that's an untested guest. That would leave your Dart VM as your "app server".

Comment: To extend Seth's last comment, Apache and nginx are faster in serving static folders (at least at the moment), although it's kind of hard to make Apache to cache smaller static files in-memory and Apache does stupid things such as parse `.htaccess` files recursively every time a request comes. Personally I'd recommend either using nginx or Dart to serve static files, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, I've updated the rewritePath() function in Seth's code some so that it doesn't rewrite assets like .dart and .css files to .html, and so that it works w/ my client-side stuff living in /web.

```
  String rewritePath(String path) {
    String newPath = path;

    if (path == '/' || path.endsWith('/')) {
      newPath = '/web${path}index.html';
    } else if (!path.endsWith('.html')) {
      if (path.contains('.')) {
        newPath = '/web${path}';
      } else {
        newPath = '/web${path}.html';
      }
    } else {
      newPath = '/web${path}.html';
    }

    //peek into how it's rewriting the paths
    print('$path -> $newPath');

    return newPath;
  }
```

It's of course super basic, and a framework that handles routing would certainly come in handy (would love to see what you're building @Kai).