# Dart httpServer 404 not found page

Tags: dart

How are 404 redirects done in Dart using HTTP server?

pseudo code:

server.addRequestHandler(notFound, redirectTo(...));

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 404 == *Not Found*. What do you mean by *redirect* ?

Comment: I suppose he means the 404 page should just redirect to another page of the site, perhaps after a delay.

Comment: Seth Ladd has a good starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13081740/how-do-i-serve-static-files-from-a-different-url-with-dart

Comment: 404 should not be used for redirect. That's what 3xx response codes are for. If you want to redirect after a delay with a 404, do that on the client with scripting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do an [URL redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection), you can use :

- a `Refresh` header :

```dart
server.addRequestHandler(notFound, (HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) {
  response.statusCode = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
  response.headers.set("Refresh", "0; url=http://www.example.com/");
  response.outputStream.close();
});
```

- a [Meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_refresh) if you want to display some text before the redirection :

```dart
server.addRequestHandler(notFound, (HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) {
  response.statusCode = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
  response.headers.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, 'text/html');
  response.outputStream.writeString(
      '<!DOCTYPE html>'
      '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5; url=\'http://example.com/\'">'
      'Page requested cannot be found. You will be redirected in few seconds...'
  );
  response.outputStream.close();
});
```

Comment: Another way is to use le location header :


  response.headers.set("location", url);

Comment: Unfortunately, redirection with a `404` status and `location` header doesn't seem to work. That's why I didn't mention this header.

Comment: I think the question is "if my server has a 404, how do I redirect to a new page" ? So this has two parts... how to capture a 404 (maybe he's asking about a 404 from a static file) and then how to redirect. He doesn't specify how the program knows how to redirect from A to B, though.

Comment: Thanks Seth for clarifying the question. Thank you Alexandre for the excellent sample. I think what I really should have been using was server.defaultRequestHandler.